# after upgrade, proto003 baker/endorser error: "Can't fetch the current event..."

Tags: upgrade

I'm not using docker; I've upgraded OPAM to 4.07.1 and just compiled the new mainnet and have also upgraded the node/blockchain; the node is running and seems happy based on logs looking like they always have.  But now running my baker/endorser for existing protocol003, for every new block that comes I get

```
003-PsddFKi3.client.scheduling: Can't fetch the current event. Waiting for new event
```

instead of the regular `No slot found for` message that is usually seen.

Is this a problem?  Seems like it wouldnt bake when the rights come?

Answer (score 1):

I went back and redid everything, apparently I may have had mistake during conversion, and maybe was using wrong binary versions between the node/baker, etc.

Someone helped me log the actual cause:

```
Error: State.Chain.get_level_index_protocol
```

which indicates that there is some kind of incompatibility between the baker daemon and node data...